# use media query to split flexbox

Tags: iphone, flexbox, media-queries

I have the following flexbox for the desktop.  How do I add a media query so on a iphone 6 I get the blue box centered followed underneath by the red box?

```css
.container{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-around;
   }
   .left, .right{
   width:40vw;
   min-height:300px;
   }
   
   .left{
   background-color:blue;
   }
   
   .right{
   background-color:red;
   }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
   <div class='left'>
   </div>
   <div class='right'>
   </div>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change flex to block in the css and change the width of left and right